# Android listView fast smoothScrollToPosition

Tags: android, listview, smooth-scrolling

I wonder how can achieve fast smooth scroll thru items in list view.
I have 3000 items in list view and if I cal method:

```
myList.smoothScrollToPosition(1700);
```

nothing happen on my tablet (it is scrolled by two or tree items and this scrolling is very ugly sticky etc.. not even close what I want), but on my virtual device this work great.
For closer items also on tablet work great. So I tray with other method where I can set duration of this method like this (I set 7ms, for one item that must scroll thru):

```
myList.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(1700, 150,1700*7);
```

And in that case also on my tablet work as I want, but if I want to do faster like 6ms per one item then again nothing happen (sticky moving by two or tree items) on my tablet.

So I wonder how can I achieve fast smoothScrolling in my listView?

btw. my tablet has android 4.0.3, on virtual device I have 4.3